# Parent to child communication not working with Angular 9 mat-tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9, mat-tab

I'm relatively new to Angular. I was trying to pass data from parent component to child component with the use of @Input(), but the changes are not reflected.
I have a parent component with a select element, I want to pass the value of the selected item to the children.
The parent component has a mat-tab-group with a few mat-tab(s).

**Parent HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Class" [formControl]="selectedClassControl" (selectionChange)="changeClassId()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let class of classes" value="{{class.id}}">{{class.classNumber}}-{{class.section}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-tab-group color="primary" (selectedIndexChange)="selectTab($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Units">
        <app-units [classId]="classId" *ngIf="selectedTab === 0"></app-units>
    </mat-tab>
    <!-- many such tabs with the same structure --> 
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Parent TS**

```
  classId : number = 0;
  classes: Class[];
  selectedClass: any;
  selectedClassControl = new FormControl(this.selectedClass);
  constructor(private classService: ClassService, private stateMgmtService: 
StateManagementService) { 
    var schoolId = this.stateMgmtService.getSchoolId();
    this.classService.getClasses(schoolId).subscribe(data =>{
      this.classes = data;
    })
  }
  selectedTab = 0;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  selectTab(event) {
    this.selectedTab = event;
  }

  changeClassId(){
    this.classId = this.selectedClassControl.value;
    console.log("ClassId changed to "+this.classId);
  }
```

**Child HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Subject" [formControl]="selectedSubjectControl" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let subject of subjects" value="{{subject.id}}">{{subject.code}}-{{subject.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Child TS**

```
  @Input() classId : number = 0;
  subjects: Subject[];
  selectedSubject: any;
  selectedSubjectControl = new FormControl(this.selectedSubject);
  constructor(private classService: ClassService) { 
    console.log("classId"+this.classId);
    if(this.classId != 0)
    classService.getSubjects(this.classId).subscribe( data => {
      this.subjects = data;
    })
  }
```

What I see is that when I change my selection in the parent component, the classId is not communicated to the child component, should I manually refresh the component for the changes to get reflected?
Any help much appreciated...
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things here. First be careful of using Subject as a class name Subject is an object in rxjs that you might accidentally be importing. I would make your class name more specific.

Next you really don't need the selectionChange event logic. Instead you can subscribe to the valueChanged property of the form control and set the classId variable whenever it changes like this

```
this.selectedClassControl.valueChanges.subscribe(e => this.classId = e),
```

next in your child component the classId will update but your Subject array won't

I would instead use a setter on your input like this

```
@Input() set classId(val: number) {
   this._classId = val;
 if(val != 0) {
  classService.getSubjects(val).subscribe( data => {
   this.subjects = data;
  }); //assuming this is an http service so no unsubscribe is required
}
}
private _classId: number = 0;
```

Comment: This worked but with a small tweak, the code had to be changed to
`classService.getSubjects(val).subscribe( data => { // this.classId was undefined`
I'm not sure why this is happenning, also I tried to do `this.classId = val`, but it threw an error saying max stack trace reached(not sure of the exact message)
@Vinez can you please explain why this is happenning?

Comment: ah ya thats my bad it was a copy paste mix up val was suppose to go there.

Comment: But how would the value of classId be set, if accessed outside the Input block it is undefined.
this.classId = val would not work as we are setting the value inside the input set block
Is there a workaround or solution to this?

Comment: appended you just make a _classId value check val if you don't need classId and remove the rest if you do need it the check _classId

Answer (score 1):

The constructor might be fired too soon for the input variable. You could try to manually listen to changes of the input variable using [`OnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) hook. Try the following

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";

export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() classId: number = 0;
  subjects: Subject[];
  selectedSubject: any;
  selectedSubjectControl = new FormControl(this.selectedSubject);

  constructor(private classService: ClassService) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("classId" + this.classId);
    if(this.classId != 0) {
      this.classService.getSubjects(this.classId).subscribe( data => {
        this.subjects = data;
      });
    }
  }

  private doSomething(input: string) {}
}
```

Comment: this would solve the problem as well we have started preferring the use of setters on @Input() instead of using DoCheck or OnChange as its cleaner and less code but this is also a valid solution.